# How to authorizing users in ASP.Net Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I have a web application and in it's login, i check that users exists in system or not, then if user was valid, add his use object to `session` as you seen below:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object doLogin(string UserName, string PassWord)
{
    try
    {
        entity = new DB();

        UserName = UserName.RemoveInjection();
        PassWord = PassWord.RemoveInjection().Encrypt();

        Manager manager = (from m in entity.Managers
                           where m.UserName.Equals(UserName)
                           && m.PassWord.Equals(PassWord)
                           select m).FirstOrDefault();

        if (manager == null)
            return new { Result = false };
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Manager", manager);
            return new { Result = true };
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new { Result = "failed", Message = ex.Message };
    }
}
```

then, in `page_load` of all pages and all `methods`, i'm check the session as you seen below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Manager"] == null)
    {
        string close = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                        window.returnValue = true;
                        parent.info('Invalid user.');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            parent.window.location.href = 'AdminLogin.aspx';

                        }, 4000);
                        </script>";
        base.Response.Write(close);
    }
}

[WebMethod]
public static object List(int start, int size, string orderBy, string orderByType)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Manager"] != null)
        // do something
    else
        return new { Result = "session" };
}
```

**I mean that is there a way to prevent from this checking in all of pages, something like filter to accessing specific forms and pages.**

Comment: write session check code in master page

Comment: is there a better way than using master pgae?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps set up special authorization in web.config based on role and/or anonymous (logged-in). you can create a different web.config for different directories if that helps.

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <!-- here. -->
```